Networkx Edges within edges
i have this problem where i wanted to see all my connected components : 1-3-4-5 and all of the edges have “good” as the attribute
When I am given only
Start,End,Condition

1,5,good
3,4,
5,7.2,good
7,8,
7.2, 8.6, poor

**expected outcome**

Start,End,Condition

1, 3, good
3, 4, good
4, 5, good
5, 7, good
7, 7.2, good
7.2, 8, poor
8, 8.6, poor

My current code is as below and I am not sure how to do it, and i think networkx is able to produce the expected outcome but i am not too sure how
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1, 5), (3,4)],etc)


How are 1-3-4-6 connected components if you only have 1-3 and 1-5 as edges?

I describe the start and end as the edges, so first row has 1 connected to 5 and the second row has connected 3 to 4. Because 3 and 4 are within 1 to 5, it means that they are all connected to each other and have condition =good

so 1,5,good means that you in fact create 1->2->3->4->5 and all edges have the attribute "good"? But since you later define 3->4 should you lose this attribute?

You can use pure python to identify the components (actually here, the overlapping intervals), then create the graph and loop over the input to relabel the edges based on the ranges:
import networkx as nx
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
from itertools import pairwise

lst = [(1, 5, 'good'),
       (3, 4, None),
       (5, 7.2, 'good'),
       (7, 8, None),
       (7.2, 8.6, 'poor'),
       (9, 10, None),
       (9.5, 9.8, 'good'),
      ]

# ensure the input is sorted by start/end
lst = sorted(lst)

# identify "connected components"
# i.e. overlapping intervals
components = []
max_end = float('nan')
for s, e, _ in lst:
    if s<=max_end:
        components[-1].update({s, e})
    else:
        components.append({s, e})
    max_end = max(e, max_end)
    
# components
# [{1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7.2, 8, 8.6}, {9, 9.5, 9.8, 10}]

# create Graph from connected components
G = nx.compose_all(map(nx.path_graph, map(sorted, components)))

# get all nodes
nodes = sorted(set().union(*components))
# [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7.2, 8, 8.6, 9, 9.5, 9.8, 10]

# label edges
for n1, n2, label in lst:
    if label:
        i1 = bisect_left(nodes, n1)
        i2 = bisect_right(nodes, n2)
        nx.set_edge_attributes(G, dict.fromkeys(pairwise(nodes[i1:i2]),
                                                {'label': label}))

print(G.edges(data=True))

Output:
[
    (1, 3, {'label': 'good'}),
    (3, 4, {'label': 'good'}),
    (4, 5, {'label': 'good'}),
    (5, 7, {'label': 'good'}),
    (7, 7.2, {'label': 'good'}),
    (7.2, 8, {'label': 'poor'}),
    (8, 8.6, {'label': 'poor'}),
    (9, 9.5, {}),
    (9.5, 9.8, {'label': 'good'}),
    (9.8, 10, {}),
]

Graph:

Related resources:

Generate graph from a list of connected components
Identifying rows with overlapping intervals efficiently (pandas)


Hi, since 2 is not in the list, it can't appear in the outcome :/

3->4 wont be relabel as 1->5 already cover it

@cyntha That's why I asked the questions, your initial example and lack of output were ambiguous. I got it now. In the end do you want a network Graph or a table? Can you use [tag:pandas]?

Also can you have ranges likes 1->5 and 2->3? Can you have conflicts (1->3 good and 2->4 bad)?

okok, sorry, my bad. I want a table as the outcome. I thought of using networkX because I thought they have way to acheive my result (though at the end need to print it out and make it as a table). I can use pandas, but i prefer not to use it as this will later have to do with x,y coordinates which i thought networkX is best to use

no there will not be conflicts. the sample won't have conflicts

Well, I don't think networkx is the right tool here. It's not designed to handle ranges as nodes/edges. I'm happy to provide a python/pandas solution if you like. You can always generate a networkx graph later on if needed, but the processing must be done elsewhere.

Sure, please do so with pandas. I am very keen to know how to do it

@cyntha I provided a hybrid python/networkx solution

It sounds like you want to find all connected components in a graph where the edges have a specific attribute (in this case, good).
If I understand correctly, you want to see the connected components formed by edges with the good attribute.
To do so, you can add the "Condition" attribute to the edges and then filters the edges based on this attribute to find the connected components:
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
edges = [
    (1, 5, "good"),
    (3, 4, ""),
]

for start, end, condition in edges:
    G.add_edge(start, end, condition=condition)

good_edges = [(u, v) for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True) if d['condition'] == 'good']
G_good = nx.Graph()
G_good.add_edges_from(good_edges)

connected_components = list(nx.connected_components(G_good)) # {1, 5}

If this solution does not meet your needs, please provide more details about your problem, and I'll be happy to help further.
